# how to combine 2 grep checks in a while loop

Tags: bash

This is basically what I'm trying to do:

```
while string1 is not present in foo.log OR string2 is present in foo.log do
    echo .
loop
```

Examples of input files:

this should keep the while running

```
string1
foo
bar
string2
```

this should keep the while running

```
foo
bar
```

this should stop the while loop

```
foo
bar
string1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"string1 is not present in foo.log OR string2 is present in foo.log" should translate to

```
while ! grep -q "string1" foo.log || grep -q "string2" foo.log; do
    echo .
done
```

Comment: And FYI, the reason why the original `grep -qv` isn't working is that it tries to find lines not matching `string1`. As long as there is a single line not matching `string1`, it's considered a success.

Comment: your solution not worked here. the file could have both strings at the same time, like

  string1
  string2
  foo

Comment: @DiegoPlentz, a little bit unclear here. Is your "string1 is not present in foo.log AND string2 is present in foo.log" supposed to operate one line at a time or on the entire file?

Comment: The problem was my logic. That "AND" should be an or. I changed the question and your answer(which was correct the way the question was). Thanks!